# How to get all combinations of word in string

Tags: javascript

I want to get all neighboring combinations of words in string like 
string `get all combinations` 
and I want to get

```
get all combinations
all combinations
get all
all
get
combinations
```

and I write next code

```js
var string = 'get all combinations';
var result = getKeywordsList(string);
document.write(result);

function getKeywordsList(text) {
    var wordList = text.split(' ');
    var keywordsList = [];
    while (wordList.length > 0) {
        keywordsList = keywordsList.concat(genKeyWords(wordList));
        wordList.shift();
    }
    return keywordsList;
}

function genKeyWords(wordsList) {
    var res = [wordsList.join(' ')];
    if (wordsList.length > 1) {
        return res.concat(genKeyWords(wordsList.slice(0, -1)));
    } else {
        return res;
    }
}
```

can I improve or simplify this task (get all neighboring combinations of words ) 
p.s. sorry for my English

Comment: If the code works as intended, it's better asked on [codereview.se].

Comment: @Sergey -- just be careful with recursive functions, they are limited depending the browser you  use. In fact wouldnt it be better to just send that list server side to handle it with PhP?

Comment: @Grimbode thanks I will be careful with it

Comment: @Jongware i didn't know about it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

hello maybe this help you

```js
    var string = 'get all combinations'    
    var sArray = string.split(' ');
    var n = sArray .length;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        document.write(sArray .slice(j, n - i + j).join(' ') + ', ');
      }
    }
```