# Javascript, take inputted string and print all possibilities

Tags: javascript

I've been searching for ours all over the web, including here for a way to solve this project I have for homework this week. To answer your question, the professor gave us a book that in no way connects with the homework so my textbook has been all but useless. I am very new to Javascript and don't even know where to begin with this project.

Project: "Write a JavaScript function that generates all combinations of an inputted word."

Example: "dog" would print: dog dgo god gdo odg ogd

I kinda wrote out the steps I need the code to make:

1. Ask user for a string. (i guess using some sort of input box but IDK which to use.)
2. Pass string to a function.
3. Function breaks the string into letters.
4. stores letters in an array.
5. Finds all combinations of stored array letters.
6. prints combinations in inner HTML.

Like I said I am very new to JS and so please explain any answers and feel free to ask questions and I'll do my best to answer them quickly.

The code i've tried:

```js
 function combo() {
    var string = prompt("Please Enter a String", "Dog");
    var strArr = string.split("");
    var temp = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        temp = strArr[i];
        console.log(temp);
        for (var j = i + 1; j < strArr.length; j++) {
            temp += strArr[j];
            console.log(temp);
        }
    }
```

```html
   

    <button onclick="combo()">Click Me!</button>
   <p id="demo"></p>
```

Like I said most of this is just what I could find online because I don't fully understand the concepts.

Edit: does anyone have an example of how I could send the input from the user to the function?

Comment: Share the code you've tried in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all combinations of word in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583491/how-to-get-all-combinations-of-word-in-string)

Comment: I don't think you tried very hard... https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57161/generate-all-possible-combinations-of-letters-in-a-word

Comment: Try googling permutations of string, should get plenty of examples.

Comment: @jmargolisvt i had looked at that post and it hadn't helped me much

Comment: @BenSmallwood Literally several answers already posted in the CodeReview link I posted.

Comment: @BenM do you know how I would link this to my HTML or send the inputted string to the function?

Comment: @BenSmallwood see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the answer found in this [CodeReview question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57161/generate-all-possible-combinations-of-letters-in-a-word), the following will work fine:

```js
function generateAnagrams(word) 
{
  if (word.length < 2) 
  {
    return [word];
  } 


  var anagrams = [];
  var before, focus, after, shortWord, subAnagrams, newEntry;

  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) 
  {
    before = word.slice(0, i);
    focus = word[i];
    after = word.slice(i + 1, word.length + 1);
    shortWord = before + after;
    subAnagrams = generateAnagrams(shortWord);

    for (var j = 0; j < subAnagrams.length; j++)
    {
      newEntry = focus + subAnagrams[j];
      anagrams.push(newEntry);
    }
  }
  return anagrams;
}

document.getElementById('btn_go').onclick = function()
{
  var words = generateAnagrams(document.getElementById('input_word').value);
  document.getElementById('output').value = words.join("\n");
}
```

```css
input, 
textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width:60%;
}

textarea {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input id="input_word" placeholder="Input your word here" />
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
<button id="btn_go">
   Go!
</button>
```